# How to change tortoisehg tab width

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Where are settings in tortoisehg to change tab size in code preview. By default it set to 8, not very comfortable to view tabbed source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Menu File -> Settings -> Tab Width
[image]